# Installing php 7.2.0RC3/4 on the raspberry pi 3 b [32 bit]

Tags: raspberry-pi, php

Is there currently a possibility for me to find a way to install php7.2RC3/4 on my pi?
I tried to install https://downloads.php.net/~remi/ (php-7.2.0RC3.tar.gz) from here but it appears to be for 64 bit, since I get the "Cannot execute binary files: Exec format error".

Consequently, I installed the pi64 OS (Debian Stretch based), but I wasn't comfortable with this Distribution, the system constantly freezes and is slow.